# Can I edit Microsoft Word 2011 Mac grammar (capitalization)?

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, grammar

The house style of the company I work for is to not capitalize "internet".  Microsoft Word for Mac 2011 flags this as a grammar error.  I tried added lowercase "internet" to the spelling dictionary, but this doesn't help.

Is there any way to tell Word that I don't want to capitalize "internet" without turning off capitalization checking altogether?

Answer (score 2):

It's a kludge, but the simplest way to tell Word you don't want to capitalise "internet" is probably to create an autocorrect entry as follows (assunming that you do not routinely switch off the relevant part of autocorrect, of course):

1. Type "internet" with a small "i"
2. select the word, and no surrounding text/space
3. in Tools->Language..., leave whichever language is selected as is,
   but check "Do not check spelling or grammar"
4. Go into Word->Preferences...->Autocorrect. The Word "internet should
   already be in the "With" box of the "Replace text as you type"
5. Check the Formatted Text radio button
6. type "internet" (without the quotes) in the Replace box.
7. click OK.

Now, when you type "internet" (or "Internet" for that matter), Word should replace it with the same word but with the "do not check..." formatting.

Comment: I'm confused: (1) Does this require that I leave "Do not check..." selected? (2) The Formatted Text box is grayed out.

Comment: @Barry Parr: (1) "instructions" may not always work as intended but right now they work here. So (2) please either follow them carefully and indicate what does not work, or try to find your own way through. (3) 'check "Do not check spelling or grammar"' means that the checkbox against "do not check spelling or grammar" should be checked (not blank, and not greyed). Checking the box should only affect the current selection - not an indication to Word that checking should never be done. (4) Here, the Formatted Text button is greyed when there is only a point selection. Anything selected there?